# Append appendices at the end of the document

Tags: environments, appendices, acmart

I am looking for a way to write appendices in the flow of my TeX text, and to have them rejected at the end of my document during rendering.

The main motivation is that I keep moving contents to and from appendices, for example to enforce some size limit on the main document. Hence I do not want to move the text physically. Wrapping it in an environment would be much more convenient.

For example, I would write something along the lines of:

```
\section{The Premisses}

Bananas are yellow. More info can be found in the appendices.

\begin{appendix}
    \section{On The Colour Of Bananas}
    The assumption that bananas are yellow was derived
    from a rigorous field study. The following table
    gathers collected data.
    ....
    ....
\end{appendix}


\section{The Shocking Truth}

Not only are bananas yellow, but pineapples, too.
Refer to appendices for a visual proof sketch.

\begin{appendix}
    \section{On The Yellow-Tooness of Pineapples}
    Here is a picture that evidences that pineapples
    are yellow.
           .    .
          / \  / \
          \_/__\_/
         /\/\/\/\/\
        /\/\/\/\/\/\
        \/\/\/\/\/\/
         \/\/\/\/\/
          \/\/\/\/
\end{appendix}


\section{The Conclusion}

It appears that most fruits are yellow.
```

And I would get something like:

```
1. The premisses
...
2. The Shocking Truth
...
3. The Conclusion
...
Appendix A. On The Colour Of Bananas
...
Appendix B. On The Yellow‐Tooness of Pineapples
...
```

Is there a dedicated way of doing this? Otherwise, what is the neater workaround?

In case it matters, I am using the document class `acmart` and the section of my document are found in separate `\input` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a package that does this but using [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/interface3) it is fairly easy to do this. First, note that there is already an `\appendix` command so you cannot call your environment `appendix` (since `\begin{XXX}...` does a little initialisation and then inserts `\XXX` into the input stream...).

The code below defines a new environment called `Appendix`. This environment uses the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package to throw the contents of the environment into a [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/interface3) "sequence". At the end of the document this sequence is regurgitated, in order, using the `\AtEndDocument` hook from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. The end result is that your MWE produces:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{environ}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_appendices_seq% define a sequence for holding the appendices
\NewEnviron{Appendix}{\seq_gput_right:No \g_appendices_seq \BODY}
\newcommand\AddAppendices{% regurgitate the appendices
  \appendix% turn all subsequent sections into appendices
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_appendices_seq {##1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% automatically print the appendices at the end of the document
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndDocument{\AddAppendices}

\begin{document}

\section{The Premisses}

Bananas are yellow. More info can be found in the appendices.

\begin{Appendix}
    \section{On The Colour Of Bananas}
    The assumption that bananas are yellow was derived
    from a rigorous field study. The following table
    gathers collected data.
    ....
    ....
\end{Appendix}

\section{The Shocking Truth}

Not only are bananas yellow, but pineapples, too.
Refer to appendices for a visual proof sketch.

\begin{Appendix}
    \section{On The Yellow-Tooness of Pineapples}
    Here is a picture that evidences that pineapples
    are yellow.
\end{Appendix}

\section{The Conclusion}

It appears that most fruits are yellow.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like to know if passed this 2 years have something changed. I trying to use your solutions but is not working correctly, isn't creating the appendix, only a section and i cannot figure out whats wrong. And i want to know if the documentclass impact in something, because i'm using report class.

Comment: Just a update, i not yet know what was the problem, but i have made to work using appendix Package and using the appendices environment instead the `\appendix`